# How to use case statements in bash by its index value?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have the following code where the user picks a file type, then I run certain code for each case:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Please enter your file type choice: '

options=(".c (C)" \
        ".cpp (C++)" \
        ".css (CSS)" \
        ".html (HTML)" \
        ".java (Java)" \
        ".ms (Groff)") 

select option in "${options[@]}" # Asks for the option choice
do
    case "${option}" in
        ".c (C)") # C programming file
            echo "C OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        ".cpp (C++)") # C++ programming file
            echo "C++ OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        ".css (CSS)") # CSS programming file
            echo "CSS OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        ".html (HTML)") # HTML File
            echo "HTML OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        ".java (Java)") # Java programming file
            echo "JAVA OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        ".ms (Groff)") # Groff markup file
            echo "GROFF OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $option"
           ;;
    esac
done
```

I was wondering how I can make it like this, where in the case statement you can address each case by the index of the array instead of the value of the array:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Please enter your file type choice: '

options=(".c (C)" \
        ".cpp (C++)" \
        ".css (CSS)" \
        ".html (HTML)" \
        ".java (Java)" \
        ".ms (Groff)") 

select option in "${options[@]}" # Asks for the option choice
do
    case "${option}" in
        1) # C programming file
            echo "C OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        2) # C++ programming file
            echo "C++ OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        3) # CSS programming file
            echo "CSS OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        4) # HTML File
            echo "HTML OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        5) # Java programming file
            echo "JAVA OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        6) # Groff markup file
            echo "GROFF OPTION SELECTED"
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $option"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I did a lot of research and I'm not the best at bash (but I'm learning). Sorry if the solution is obvious but I would appreciate your help, that you.

Comment: Note that `sh` doesn't support arrays at all, meaning the datatypes it has don't _have_ indexes, so I'm not clear why it's tagged here.

Comment: Sorry, I will remove it.

Comment: Also, note that indexes start from 0, not 1.

Comment: Is the `option` structure really a good choice here? Its point is to let the user enter a number instead of typing in the full option, but then you want to translate that back into a number... and it won't even be the same number, because bash arrays are zero-indexed! Why not just print the numbers and options yourself, and use `read` to get the option number directly?

Comment: After `select`, the index is in `$REPLY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On bash 4.0 or newer, you can build a reverse index as an associative array:

```
declare -A options_reverse=()
for idx in "${!options[@]}"; do
  val=${options[$idx]}
  options_reverse[$val]=$idx
done
```

...after doing which, `${options_reverse[$option]}` will map to the desired index.

Combined with the rest of your program, this would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

PS3='Please enter your file type choice: '

options=(
  ".c (C)"
  ".cpp (C++)"
  ".css (CSS)"
  ".html (HTML)"
  ".java (Java)"
  ".ms (Groff)"
)

declare -A options_reverse=()
for idx in "${!options[@]}"; do
  val=${options[$idx]}
  options_reverse[$val]=$idx
done

select option in "${options[@]}"; do
  case "${options_reverse[$option]}" in
    0) echo "C OPTION SELECTED";;
    1) echo "C++ OPTION SELECTED";;
    2) echo "CSS OPTION SELECTED";;
    3) echo "HTML OPTION SELECTED";;
    4) echo "JAVA OPTION SELECTED";;
    5) echo "GROFF OPTION SELECTED";;
    *) echo "invalid option $option";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Though I do see where you're going with this, there seems to be an error on ```options_reverse[$val]=$idx``` in the for loop. It tells me 'line 17: .c (C): syntax error: operand expected (error token is ".c (C)")'.

Comment: @HusseinEsmail, ...see it working correctly with bash 5.0.3 in an online interpreter at https://ideone.com/uvyF7Z (as I say in the answer, it should work with any release newer than 4.0; before 4.0, associative arrays aren't supported at all).

Comment: @HusseinEsmail, that said, any version of bash that has a problem with that line will _also_ have a problem with `declare -A`. I don't suppose you perhaps changed it to `declare -a`? They're not the same thing.

Comment: @HusseinEsmail I can confirm that the code in the answer is working without an issue with the `bash` version 4.4.20 (the lowest version I have right now)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I noticed my mac is still on bash version 3.7. I'm in the process of updating it right now, and I will test this code again after I updated it properly.

Comment: @HusseinEsmail, yes this code has worked fine for me also.

Answer (score 2):

From `help option`:

> The line read is saved in the variable `REPLY`.

Comment: I don't believe this helps me. Instead of accessing each case by its reply, I want to access it by the index of the reply in the array. If I had array=("first" "second" "third"), I want to access it by 1, 2, 3 (or 0, 1, 2 depending on what bash uses).

Comment: If you type in `3` and press enter, then REPLY will contain `3` and not `.css (CSS)`, so this works (you have to subtract 1 though, since `select` shows 1-based while bash arrays are 0-based)